# How to check cpu history

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, centos7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrHxB.png)

My server recently had a problem causing it to stop working. So how can I check what application cpu is serving at that time? My server is running a web application and cronjob. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no historical record of resource usage on Linux without you setting it up beforehand.

`atop` or `collectd` are able to record resource usage on a per-process basis.

Monitoring solutions like `monit` or `Nagios/Icinga` can be set up to record process names as well.